# Link to "an account" in "add comment" is dead

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, comments

When I am viewing a question while not logged in, it shows, under the question:

> add comment (requires [an account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/users/login) with [50 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment))

However, the link to [an account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/users/login) is dead.

[image: link to "an account" in "add comment" is dead]

---

Here's a screenshot to the result 404 page:

[image: result 404 page]

Same 404 page on

- Chrome (Normal Mode / Incognito Mode)
- Opera 12.16 (Private Browsing Mode)
- IE 10 (Normal Mode / InPrivate Mode)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/users/login only works if you are not logged in.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It shows "Page not found" for me when I'm not logged in.

Comment: Are you sure you're not logged in?  I verified by opening an incognito window in Chrome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Edited question to add more detail.

Comment: Should be just /users/login

Comment: taking a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in the next deployment