# Page not found error when joining SciFi SE

Tags: bug, sign-up

Today while I browsed around the SE sites I found an interesting answer on SciFi Meta SE. The answer can be found [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) if relevant. Since I don't have an account there yet I was prompted to sign up or sign in. So I clicked the link and was redirected to the [confirm your new account page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/join?ssrc=votedialog&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fscifi.meta.stackexchange.com%2fquestions%2f9335%2fhow-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question%2f9337%239337). Then I clicked on "Confirm and create this account" and was greeted with a [404 page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm), which is obviously a dead end.

How can I create an account on SciFi Meta SE anyway?

Comment: You can create an account on the main SciFi site; does that work?

Comment: Now i have both a meta and normal SciFi account, after creating the account on the main site. It is still strange i can't just create on for meta which should (in my opinion) add an account for the main page as well.

Comment: Oh, since i see it just now in the related section, this seems to be an error around for quite a while, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269699/join-this-community-gives-404-when-called-from-add-comment-on-a-site-meta and maybe also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190255/link-to-an-account-in-add-comment-is-dead, although the latter might be too old to be valid.

Comment: But still no solution for it i guess?

Comment: To get attention for the original request, you can follow the steps at [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).